# Problem in adding multi filter to odata service

Tags: filter, odata, sapui5

I have the following code. I am trying to read 3 different values for PO from input fields then displaying the result in list. Program is working fine for single input but for multiple inputs i am facing issues.

```
var oV1 = this.getView().byId("oInput").getValue();
var oV2 = this.getView().byId("oInput1").getValue();
var oV3 = this.getView().byId("oInput2").getValue();                                     


var oFilter = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Ebeln", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oV1)];          
var oFilter1 = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Ebeln", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oV2)];
var oFilter2 = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Ebeln", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oV3)];



var orFilter =new Array(new sap.ui.model.Filter({filters:[oFilter, oFilter1, oFilter2],and:true}));

   var oView1 = this.getView();
   var oTable = oView1.byId("myTable");
   var oBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");
   if(oV1 === "")
   {
       oBinding.filter( [] );
       oBinding.refresh(true);
   }
   else
   {
     oBinding.filter(orFilter);
```

At the above oBinding.filter I am receiving following error.
Filter in Aggregation of Multi filter has to be instance of sap.ui.model.Filter -

Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You wrapped your filters in 1000 layers of Arrays which doesn't make sense.

Just create a single array which contains Filter **objects**:

```js
// Filter, FilterOperator, and FilterType required from "sap/ui/model/*"
const aFilter = [
  new Filter("Ebeln", FilterOperator.Contains, sV1),
  new Filter("Ebeln", FilterOperator.Contains, sV2),
  new Filter("Ebeln", FilterOperator.Contains, sV3),
];
oListBinding.filter(aFilter, FilterType.Application);
```

---

I know this isn't a code review but some suggestions:

- No one uses `new Array()`. Just use `[]`.
- Also you used Hungarian notation but every one of your variable names begins with `o`. `o` means object. Some of your variables are not objects but strings (like `oV1`, better would be `sV1`) or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

For the `filters` aggregation, [sap.ui.model.Filter](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter%23constructor) accepts a `Filter[]`. But because `oFilter` already is a `Filter[]`, `[oFilter, oFilter1, oFilter2]` is a `Filter[][]`, so that won't work.

To make it work, just remove the surrounding `[]` from the filter definitions, like so:
`var oFilter = new Filter(...);`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. Issue is resolved now.

Comment: @Ahmed Consider to upvote helpful answers in place of commenting "thank you".