# Passing filters in OData service SAP UI5 to ABAP

Tags: javascript, filter, odata, sapui5, abap

I am reading two parameters from URL.

```
 var spayid = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().get("payid"); 
 var spaydt = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().get("paydt");
```

Now I have to pass these two filter options in my odata service.

```
this.getView().setModel(new ODataModel("proxy/http/FIORI-DEV.abc.com:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_OD_SRV/?sap-client=100", {    
json : true,
useBatch : false})
```

Entity Name= PDetailSet
Field name for spayid is Laufid and spaydt is Laufdt.

Please help how to pass filters in odata service.

NB: I have also add the filters in the following way.

```
var filter1= new sap.ui.model.Filter(
    { path: "Laufi", operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, value1: spayid });
var filter2= new sap.ui.model.Filter(
    { path: "Laufd", operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, value1: spaydt });
```

Comment: I have also add the filters in the following way.     var filter1= new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                      path: "Laufi",
                      operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
                      value1: spayid
                     });
                     var filter2= new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                      path: "Laufd",
                      operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
                      value1: spaydt
                     });

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem in adding multi filter to odata service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203299/problem-in-adding-multi-filter-to-odata-service)

Comment: I want to pass filter parameters on ODATA service so that only results which are required comes in the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter with "OR" And "AND" Conditions on Multiple Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433200/filter-with-or-and-and-conditions-on-multiple-fields)

Comment: This question seems to be same as [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62949276/5846045). Is it still about the master detail problem? If then, `Filter` is a wrong approach. Instead of asking multiple questions about the same problem, consider following the official _[learning path](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218)_ from the documentation first.

Answer (score 2):

A model itself can not be filtered, but a binding can. So if you bind your dataset to a table i.e. you could filter that binding with your filters, as described in your comments.

That would look like this:

```
oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(filter1);
```

To combine your two filters, you can use another filter, which has the advantage that you can decide wheter to use "and" or "or". You can see a detailed example for that in the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter%23constructor).