# How to bind an entity object on a Detail page

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am developing a master detail Fiori app using SAP UI5. As the details contains more than 40 columns, I made separate OData services for master & detail.

In Master page, data are coming correctly. Now my task is that on any table line, when user clicks on Detail, next page will be open with details base on **two key values of master table**.

I'm  getting two keys in variables in detail page as follows and it is working fine:

```js
var spayid = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().get("payid");
var spaydt = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().get("paydt");
```

Next, I have created two filters as follows which is also working fine.

```js
var filter1 = new Filter({
  path: "Laufi",
  operator: FilterOperator.EQ,
  value1: spayid
});
var filter2 = new Filter({
  path: "Laufd",
  operator: FilterOperator.EQ,
  value1: spaydt
});
```

Now I am calling OData service which is also working fine:

```js
var oODataModel = new ODataModel("proxy/http/FIORI-DEV.abc.com:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZASA_FI_pay_D_SRV?sap-client=100", {
  json: true,
  useBatch: false
});
this.getView().setModel(oODataModel);
```

I don't know now how to filter data. What should be included in above so that it will filter data according to my filters `filer1` and `filter2`? I have tried following but it is not working.

```js
  filters : [ filter1, filter2 ],
  json: true,
  useBatch: false
```

I am very good in ABAP but not an expert in SAPUI5. I am in learning phase.

First of all, I was thinking to pass parameters on OData service so that only the required data are fetched. Means my OData call should be like this:

```js
new ODataModel("proxy/http/FIORI-DEV.abc.com:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZASA_FI_PAYMENT_D_SRV/PdetailSet(Laufi= spayid, Laufd = spaydt)?sap-client=100");
```

But this seems not like possible.

Second option is that I will fetch whole details in OData service and then during binding to table I will apply filter.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870579/5846045. I also added a sample demo there. You don't need to use or implement `$filter` queries for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `sap.ui.model.Filter` class is usually to apply filters to lists on the UI. For example, if you have a list of items and you want to limit that list to a subset of items which fulfills certain criteria.

But what you have here appears to be a classic master-detail scenario where you have a list of items and then when the user selects one show more information about that **one** item.

The usual solution for such a scenario is to assign the full model to the detail-view and then use an [element binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f05e8b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) (also known as "context binding") on the view to tell it which item to display.

When the source of the item is a click on an element which already had an element binding, then you can actually retrieve the correct binding path from the click event and just apply it to your detail-view.

[From one of the official demos](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.core.tutorial.databinding/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.databinding.13/code):

```
onItemSelected: function(oEvent) {
    var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource();
    var oContext = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext("products");
    var sPath = oContext.getPath();
    var oProductDetailPanel = this.byId("productDetailsPanel");
    oProductDetailPanel.bindElement({ path: sPath, model: "products" });
}
```

When you don't have any convenient way to get an element path from, then you have to construct one yourself:

```
var detailPanel = this.getView().byId("idOfDetailPanel");
detailPanel.bindElement("PdetailSet(Laufi = " + spayid +", Laufd = " + spaydt + ")");
```

The latter code snippet does of course assume that the oData-service actually supports access with a key consisting of `laufi` and `laufd`. This is decided by:

- The definition of the key fields of the entity type in the SAP Gateway Service Builder (transaction SEGW)
- The ABAP implementation of the method `get_entity` of the data provider class of that oData-service.